# Named regular expression back reference in PHP

Tags: php, regex, pcre, backreference

Using PHP 5.5+ regular expressions, I'd like to use named backreferences to capture a group.

For example, I'd like the following texts to match:

```
1-1
2-2
```

but not the following

```
8-7
```

When I try using backreferences, however, PHP is marking it as match found:

```
/* This statement evaluates to 1 */
preg_match("/(?<one>[1-9])\-(?<two>\\g<one>)/", "8-7");
```

Is there a workaround for this other than using numbered references?

Comment: Isn't this what you're looking for? `/(?<one>[1-9])\-(\\g<one>)/` Caveat: I'm not familiar with PHP semantics for regexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this excerpt from [PCRE documentation](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt):

> For compatibility with Oniguruma, the non-Perl syntax `\g` followed by 
>   a name or a number enclosed either in angle brackets or single quotes,
>   is an alternative syntax for referencing a  subpattern  as  a 
>   subroutine, possibly  recursively.
>
> Note  that `\g{...}` (Perl syntax) and `\g<...>` (Oniguruma syntax) are
>   not synonymous. The former is a back reference; the latter is a 
>   subroutine call.

By using the `\g<one>`, you do not refer to the match, but to the subpattern, see the explanation on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/dP7tW9/1).

> `\g<one>` recurses the subpattern named `one`

You need to use `\1` to actually match the same text captured in the first group.

```
(?<one>[1-9])\-(?<two>\1)
```

Or (the named back-reference to the actual text),

```
(?<one>[1-9])\-(?<two>\g{one})
```

> `\1` matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing
>   group

See [a numbered demo](https://regex101.com/r/dP7tW9/2) and a [named back-reference demo](https://regex101.com/r/dP7tW9/3).